# How do you generate an Excel 2007 file in ASP.NET without getting a warning message?

Tags: asp.net, excel

Whenever I open an xls file I generated on my ASP.NET page with Excel 2007, I get the following error:

> The file you are trying to open, 'filename.xls', is in a different
>   format than specified by the file extension. Verify that the file is
>   not corrupted and is from a trusted source before opening the file. Do
>   you want to open the file now?

If I click 'Yes', everything looks fine, but it's annoying to our customers to have to click through it each time.  If they use 2003, no problem, but on 2007 it gives this error.  Here's the code I use:

```
string style = @"<style> .text { mso-number-format: \@ } </style> ";

Response.Clear();
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename=OperationsReport_Rejects_{0}.xls", DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyyMMdd")));
Response.Charset = "";
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";

StringWriter stringWrite = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);

reportOperationsRejectsGridView.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
Response.Write(style);
Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
Response.End();
```

Does anyone know what is causing it to behave differently on 2003 and 2007?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Office 2007 uses XML based file formats that are different from the previous binary file formats.

What Excel 2007 saves is not an `.xls` file, but an `.xlsx` file.

What you are creating is actually neither. It's an HTML export of an excel file. Some versions will seamlessly import the HTML as an excel document, some versions will warn you that it's actually not an Excel document, before importing it.

If you create an actual `.xls` file, Excel 2007 will open it in compatibility mode without complaining.

Answer (score 0):

Excel 2003 and 2007 use different formats, unless the user specifically does a "Save As" and chooses a backwardly-compatible format.

A quick look in a hex viewer or hex editor will show you the large difference in the file formats.

Comment: Version 2007 would have .xlsx extension

Comment: @DJ: Not necessarily. You can give it any extension you want; heck, do a Save As and save it as an Excel 2007 file but give it a .JPG extension and it saves as a JPEG. There are still basic differences in the format as well; I get files in either of the formats all the time. As I said, look at the files in a hex viewer or editor.

Answer (score 0):

[SpreadsheetGear for .NET](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) can save as real xls or xlsx workbooks - avoiding this error message.

You can see a number of live samples on our Excel Reporting Samples page [here](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/excel.aspx) and download the free trial [here](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/downloads/register.aspx).

Disclaimer: I own SpreadsheetGear LLC